# Show $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is or isn't uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm pretty sure $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ is uniformly continuous but having a hard time proving it.  If I let $\varepsilon > 0$ and try to get $\delta$ so that $|f(x)-f(y)| = |\sqrt[3]{x} - \sqrt[3]{y}|<\varepsilon$ I don't see how to relate this to an arbitrary $|x-y|<\delta$.

I thought about $|\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[3]{y}|^3 < \varepsilon^3$ is

$$|x-y+(3\sqrt[3]{xy^2}-3\sqrt[3]{x^2y})|$$

but I don't see a way forward from here.

I know the function behaves significantly differently on $(0,1)$ and $(-\infty, -1) \cup (1,\infty)$ so I might want to break this into two proofs, where since $x^{1/3}$ is point-wise continuous then it's continuous on the compact set $[-1,1]$ and all that remains is to prove it on the rest---although I'm not seeing how to do that.

(However, this worries me:  I don't see a theorem in Rudin about ``A function uniformly continuous on a set $A$ and a set $B$ is therefore uniformly continuous on $A\cup B$ where $A\cup B$ is [some relevant property here, like being an interval or something].''  So I'm not sure how secure this proof strategy is.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is on $[0,1]$ since a continuous function on a closed bounded interval is uniformly continuous.  For $x\ge 1$, 
$$|f'(x)| = 1/3x^{-2/3} \le 1/3.$$
Invoke the mean value theorem to get unform continuity on $[1,\infty)$. Now spread the wealth to the whole line by the oddness of this function.

Answer (score 2):

A classical theorem (one that hopefully has come up in your real analysis class) is that a real function that is continuous on a closed, bounded interval is uniformly continuous. Thus for any big $N$, we know that $x^{1/3}$ is uniformly continuous on $[-N,N]$, and so the problem region should be recognized as $x\rightarrow\infty$. In particular, hopefully you have seen a proof that $f(x)=x^2$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$; is there a way you can adapt this proof to suit the case when $f(x)=x^{1/3}$? No.
Away from zero, on the set $(-\infty,-N]\cup[N,\infty)$ you should be able to prove uniform continuity.

In short, yes, if a function is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$ as well as $[b,c]$, then it will be uniformly continuous on the interval $[a,c]$. Think about how you might prove this, and indeed will generalize to any finite number of intervals...

Comment: I have seen the proof that $x^2$ was not continuous but I thought that essentially turned on the fact that the function values get far apart even if when the inputs stay close together, provided you to far enough away from 0.  Since that's not so with $\sqrt[3]{x}$ I thought it would mean the function is uniformly continuous far from 0.

Comment: Er, maybe I misunderstood your hint, I'll think some more.

Comment: Yes, let me rephrase...

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your worry about whether uniform continuity on $[a,b]$ and $[b,c]$ is enough to conclude uniform continuity on $[a,c]$, I think this detail is important enough to merit a proof.

Given $\epsilon > 0$, there exist $\delta_1 > 0$ and $\delta_2 > 0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon/2$ provided that either of these conditions is met:

- $x,y \in [a,b]$ and $|x-y| < \delta_1$
- $x,y \in [b,c]$ and $|x-y| < \delta_2$

But what if $x\in [a,b]$ and $y \in [b,c]$? Let's suppose this is the case. Let $\delta = \min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$. Suppose that $|x-y| < \delta$. Then $b$ lies between $x$ and $y$, so $|x-b| < \delta \leq \delta_1$. Therefore, $|f(x) - f(b)| < \epsilon/2$. Similarly, $|b-y| < \delta \leq \delta_2$, so $|f(b) - f(y)| < \epsilon / 2$. (Note that we have exploited the fact that $b$ is contained in both intervals.) Therefore, by the triangle inequality,
$$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq |f(x) - f(b)| + |f(b) - f(y)| < \epsilon$$
so now all cases are covered, so the "spreading the wealth" technique of establishing uniform continuity on a finite number of adjacent intervals is legit.

Answer (score 1):

Any function $x^\alpha,\enspace 0\le\alpha\le 1$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbf R$ because :

- it is continuous, hence it is uniformly continuous on any bounded closed interval.
- its derivative is bounded from above by $\alpha$ on $[1+\infty)$, hence it is *Lipschitz* on $[1,+\infty)$.
- it is an *odd* function.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x) := \sqrt[3]{x}$ is uniformly continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ because of the inequality:
$$\big| \sqrt[3]{x} - \sqrt[3]{y}\big| \leq \sqrt[3]{|x-y|}\; ,$$
which holds for every $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.

In general, if $\alpha \in ]0,1]$, the function $f(x):=|x|^\alpha$ is uniformly continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ because of the inequality:
$$\big| |x|^\alpha - |y|^\alpha \big| \leq |x-y|^\alpha\; ,$$
which express the fact that $f$ is *Hölder-continuous*.